# Charts on Questions for Programming Language

Tags: feature-request, tags, sorting

I remembered that the number of monthly questions for each language could be a nice indicator of the programming language popularity, at least here on stackoverflow. Would you consider to implement something like this?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. It's not terribly meaningful. That said you can look at the data yourself on http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: No, it does not show popularity, it only shows which language has more dumb developers. ;)

Comment: Ok, Ok.. Answered questions would do the trick better. This is meant to evaluate how much support from the language community may you get in SO.

Comment: That's also a subjective figure. If the question gets answered depends on multiple factors: Is it clear/good? How complicated is it? Is it even solvable? Does the right user see it?

Comment: It's a statistical indicator about something that is qualitative! There's no way to do it in an objective way!

Answer (score 4):

The number of monthly questions for each language isn't really an indicator of programming language *popularity*.  It doesn't take into account the difficulty of learning the language or the availability of proper documentation (and probably many other factors).

That being said, Sam Saffron ([waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles)) wrote a SEDE query recently that shows [how many questions per month each tag in the top 10 tags gets](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59301/questions-per-month-top-10-tags-compared). (Click on the Graph tab right above the results.)