# Number of questions using a tag per period of time

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Charts on Questions for Programming Language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120823/charts-on-questions-for-programming-language)

Can we see how many questions per month, quarter, year were raised with a particular tag?

I'm curious to see the trends ...

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120823/153020

Comment: Found it... http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59301/questions-per-month-top-10-tags-compared

Comment: You can always adapt that to suit your needs slightly if it's not quite what you were looking for.