# How to see the number questions asked over time for a tag?

Tags: support, questions

I know that this question exists:

[Number of questions using a tag per period of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120985/number-of-questions-using-a-tag-per-period-of-time)

and is marked as a duplicate.

However, neither the comments in that one, nor the one linked that it duplicates, actually shows how to see questions asked over time for a tag.   They point to this thing:  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59301/questions-per-month-top-10-tags-compared.
(which does something similar, but not especially close)

Similarly, there is this cool thing: [http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/](http://hewgill.com/%7Egreg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/) but it only shows time trend as a percentage of total questions, rather than as an absolute number of questions.  It also doesn't work for some tags (for example, it refuses to display a result for 'systemc').

So my question is quite specific: how can I see the number of questions asked for a specific tag over time?

(I know that a meta answer to this is likely to be "write some code like the first example above", but that's far outside my current skillset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly the following two data queries would answer your question for the systemc tag:

```
select datepart(yy,creationdate) *100 
     + datepart(mm,creationdate) as yyyymm
      , count(*) as cnt
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname='systemc'
group by datepart(yy,creationdate) *100 
     + datepart(mm,creationdate)
order by 1,2
```

[Number of questions asked for a specific tag over time (absolute)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/174729/number-of-questions-asked-for-a-specific-tag-over-time-absolute)

And a cumulative query for the same tag:

```
 select datepart(yy,creationdate) *100 
     + datepart(mm,creationdate) as yyyymm
     , sum(count(p.id)) 
        over (
           order by  datepart(yy,creationdate) *100 
                   + datepart(mm,creationdate)
           ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING )
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname='systemc'
group by datepart(yy,creationdate) *100 
   + datepart(mm,creationdate) 
     order by 1
```

[Number of questions asked for a specific tag over time (cumulative)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/174730/number-of-questions-asked-for-a-specific-tag-over-time-cumulative#graph)

Keep in mind that tags can be applied at any time. I didn't take that into account here, I simply take the post creation date (otherwise it would require a join with PostHistory rows of type 3 and 6 and some nasty text compare to figure out when tags were applied or removed.)

Comment: Excellent!    Post creation date is definitely what I was asking about, it doesn't matter (from my perspective) when it was tagged.